# Finds Forms in HTML using Python and regular expression

Tags: python, regex, forms

I have the following code that checks if there is a formular content in an email body but I did not understand what does this string `'<\s?\/?\s?form\s?>'` means and if there is another method to check formular content existence in an email?

This is the code I wrote:

```
class HTMLFormFinder(FeatureFinder):
    def getFeature(self, message):
        import re
        super(HTMLFormFinder, self).getFeature(message)
        payload = utils.getpayload(message).lower()
        return re.compile(r'<\s?\/?\s?form\s?>', re.IGNORECASE).search(payload)!= None
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have HTML then use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or `lxml`

Comment: You can use use [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aHS4Xb/2) to find out what each regular expression means (upper right side by default) if you don't want to read up on regexes as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's what's called a *regular expression*. It's a way to match strings that follow a particular pattern.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html

Here `r'<\s?\/?\s?form\s?>'` describes a `<form>` HTML tag with several fallbacks in case of bad/malformed html, specifically it handles whitespaces that may appear beside the tag name `form`.

A better way of checking the presence of forms is to use an XML/HTML parser, like ElementTree, BeautifulSoup, because they handle bad/incorrect HTML much better than regular expressions ever can. But if you want to keep it simple, the regex you have should suffice.

- https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html
- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Using BeautifulSoup you can do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
has_form = len(soup.find('form')) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read more on regular expressions here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Specifically `\s` matches any whitespace charachter.